# Listbox Form Navigation & Record Summary in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, listbox, navigation, summary

I'm working on a project in Access 2010 where I am creating a form with a subform. On the side of my form I have a Listbox control which I would like to update with the `FirstName` of person information records entered into my subform. Additionally I would like the Listbox to be clickable for easy navigation of my users so they can simply click on a persons name and have it load the record into the subform. Is there an easy way to accomplish this, or am I doomed to use VBA? If so I would really like some assistance. Sample code would be a life saver.

To provide some context, here are some sample tables:

```
Families (ID, LastName, HomeAddress, City, State, Zip)
People (ID, FirstName, FamilyID, Phone, Email)
```

**Requirements**:

- The Listbox called "All Members" should display all family members for the current `FamilyID`
- Should auto-update upon each newly added family member
- Should load the subform upon clicking a `FirstName` with that person's data

Here are some pictures of the Form/Subform & select Properties to help with understanding my goals :)

[image]
[image]

For the last several hours I've been trying to find an answer for this prior to coming here. You will help me more than you know. Thank you so much to whoever can help me solve this question ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible to do this with no coding at all. Make sure that the bound column of the listbox is FamilyID and that FamilyID is in the recordet of the subform control form (contents), then set the subform control properties like so (note: control, not contents)

```
Link Master Fields :  NameOfListBox
Link Child Fields  :  FamilyID
```

**Further Information re Comment**

[Recordset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recordset) is not a property, it is a word that you are going to come across regularly if you continue to work with Access.

I misread your requirements, it is People.ID that needs to be the bound column so:

**Listbox : FamilyMembers**

```
Data Tab
RowSource : SELECT People.ID, People.FirstName FROM People         
            WHERE (((People.FamilyID)=[Forms]![Families]![ID])) 
            ORDER BY People.FirstName;

Bound Column  : 1

Format Tab
Column Count  : 2
Column Widths : 0cm;2.54cm
```

**Subform Control**

```
Link Master Fields : FamilyMembers
Link Child Fields  : ID
```

**Form of Subform Control**

```
Record Source : SELECT [People].[ID], [People].[FirstName], etc FROM [People]
```

Comment: I can't find the "RecordSet" property of the SubForm, and it's not allowing me to set the "Link Master Fields" because it says not the same data type. It also complains about setting the "Bound Column" to text because it "isn't valid for this field." What am I doing wrong? I suspect it's because I can't find the RecordSet? Not sure if that's what you were intending to spell.

Comment: I updated my post with pictures. I'm having trouble implementing what you suggested. Some help would be tremendously appreciated. :)

Comment: @Chiramisu I have added some notes.

Comment: @Chiramisu You must type it in, not select. This has been an option since at least Access 2000.

Comment: Aye, I tried that when you answered originally and it wouldn't let me, but I'll give it another try in a couple hours when I get home. I sure hope I can get this working, it would really help my end-user experience I think. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: The above is all tested preposting, but I have done similar in several versions of Access.

Comment: I really appreciate your attempt, but I'm convinced that you or I are missing some crucial detail. Access just will NOT accept any of what you have suggested in any order I attempt. Everything pops up an error such as, "The value you entered isn't valid for this field" and then clears the box of what I'd entered. You also have contradicting info, do I put '1' in Bound Column or 'People.ID' because the latter provides the previously mentioned error. Furthermore using the query you suggested for the form results in erroneous returns and corrupts the forms. Nothing is working >.<

Comment: Even though I have done similar things many times, I copied the information above from a fresh set-up to ensure i had it right. You are clearly quite new to access, bound column refers to the column that is bound to the control, this is indicated by the bound column property, which is numeric. The bound column is People.ID, the first column, therefore the bound column property is set to 1. If people ID was the third column the property would be set to 3. cont ...

Comment: cont ... Regarding the query, I do not know all the details of your form, so can only provide examples. Create the query in the query design window, ensuring that the names match the names you are using (forms etc) and test that it works, then switch to SQL view and cut and paste the result. A query that refers to a form in this way is quite basic to Access.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4576/discussion-between-remou-and-chiramisu)